# Why doesn't __del__ work properly

Tags: python, class

I think this is the most common question on interviews:

```
class A:
     def __init__(self, name):
          self.name = name
     def __del__(self):
          print self.name,

aa = [A(str(i)) for i in range(3)]
for a in aa:
    del a
```

And so what output of this code and why.
Output will be is nothing and why?
Thats because a is ref on object in list and then we call del method we remove this ref but not object?

Comment: Who's asking you to describe the result of a somewhat obscure and useless piece of code with behavior that is indeterminate or undefined according to the language spec itself in an interview?  Are these C or Java programmers trying to interview for a Python position?

Comment: lol, I get this question about 3 or 4 times ))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least 2 references to the object that `a` references (variables are *references* to objects, they are not the objects themselves).  There's the one reference inside the list, and then there's the reference "`a`".  When you `del a`, you remove one reference (the variable `a`) but not the reference from inside the list.

Also note that Python doesn't guarantee that `__del__` will ever be called ...

Comment: Isn't it redundant to `del a` anyway?  Won't the reference count for the object `a` labels be decremented on the next iteration of the loop no matter what?

Comment: Agreed about the final point: running the OP's code as a standalone program eventually produces "2 1 0" under CPython 2.7.3, but produces *no* output under PyPy 1.9.1 or Jython 2.5.1, as `__del__` is never called.

Comment: @sr2222 presumably yes (except for the last element in the list)

Comment: @DSM -- Yeah, I figured out what you were saying and deleted my comment :).  Thanks for providing that concrete example.

Answer (score 4):

`__del__` gets called when an object is destroyed; this will happen after the last possible reference to the object is removed from the program's accessible memory.  Depending on the implementation this might happen immediately or might be after some time.

Your code just removes the local name `a` from the execution scope; the object remains in the list so is still accessible.  Try writing `del aa[0]`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

> Note del x doesn’t directly call `x.__del__()` — the former decrements the reference count for x by one, and the latter is only called when x‘s reference count reaches zero.

`__del__` is triggered when the garbage collector finds an object to be destroyed.  The garbage collector will try to destroy objects with a reference count of 0.  `del` just decouples the label in the local namespace, thereby decrementing the reference count for the object in the interpreter.  The behavior of the garbage collector is for the most part considered an implementation detail of the interpreter, so there's no guarantee that `__del__` on objects will be called in any specific order, or even at all.  That's why the behavior of this code is undefined.